# How to add security constraints in .clsss files to strict user decompiles class files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have my java application now i want to add security in my classes so that no one can de-compile my class files or open jar files.
i also want to add constraints in my web.xml file so that no one can try to access from another servlet.

Comment: Check out "Java class obfuscation"

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add security in my classes so that no one can de-compile my class files or open jar files.

You can't.  It is mathematically impossible.

If someone can get hold of the JAR file / ".class" files, they can extract and decompile the classes.  (There are ways to make it a bit harder ... but there is nothing you can do to stop a skilled and motivated attacker ... apart from not delivering code to him, in any form.)

> I also want to add constraints in my web.xml file so that no one can try to access from another servlet.

Also impossible:

- If you are talking about another servlet in the same web container, then anything you can put into the web.xml file can be edited out by the person who controls web container.
- If you are talking about a servlet in another web container, then there is no way you can *reliably* distinguish a servlet making a request from a web browser making a request.  All of the clues (e.g. request headers) can easily be spoofed.